# How change a default parameters value in jQuery function?

Tags: jquery, validation, jquery-validation-engine

I have not experience in jQuery. I use validation plugin. But I should change position of error message baloon. Here is default parameters for validation function.

```
    a.validationEngine = { defaults: { validationEventTrigger: "blur", scroll: true, 
    focusFirstField: true, promptPosition: "topRight", bindMethod: "bind", 
    inlineAjax: false, ajaxFormValidation: false, ajaxFormValidationURL: false, 
    onAjaxFormComplete: a.noop, onBeforeAjaxFormValidation: a.noop, 
    onValidationComplete: false, isOverflown: false, overflownDIV: "",
    binded: false, showArrow: true, isError: false,
    ajaxValidCache: {}, autoPositionUpdate: false, InvalidFields: [], 
    onSuccess: false, onFailure: false } }
```

I want to change **promptPosition: "topRight"** to **promptPosition: "bottomLeft"**.
When I change that parameter's value at the top function, it works.

In page I want to add **promptPosition: "bottomLeft"** parameter to following function. How can I do it?

```
<script>
 jQuery(document).ready(function () {
     jQuery('#userSignInForm').validationEngine('init');
        jQuery('#signInButton').click(function () {
            jQuery('#userSignInForm .loading').animate({ opacity: 1 }, 850);
            if (jQuery('#userSignInForm').validationEngine('validate')) {
                jQuery.post('/Profile/SignIn', {
                    UserName: jQuery('#UserName').val(),
                    Password: jQuery('#Password').val(),
                    formname: 'user_SignIn_Form',
                    formtype: 'userSignInF'
                }, function () {
                    jQuery('#userSignInForm .loading').hide();
                });
                return false;
            } else {
                return false;
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Send the parameters on initialisation :

```
jQuery('#userSignInForm').validationEngine('init', {
   promptPosition: "bottomLeft"
});
```

instead of

```
jQuery('#userSignInForm').validationEngine('init');
```

should do the trick.

[Docs for jQuery Validation engine initialisation here](https://github.com/posabsolute/jQuery-Validation-Engine#instantiation)

Answer (score 1):

#### Did you read the [docs](https://github.com/posabsolute/jQuery-Validation-Engine#instantiation)?

> When using options, the default behavior is to only initialize ValidationEngine, so attachment needs to be done manually.

```
<script>
  $(document).ready(function(){
    $("#formID").validationEngine('attach', {promptPosition : "centerRight", scroll: false});
 });
</script>
```

#### In your code:

You need to set this in the initialization. Replace:

```
jQuery('#userSignInForm').validationEngine('init');
```

With:

```
jQuery('#userSignInForm').validationEngine('init', {
  promptPosition : "bottomLeft"
});
```